# Perl -- 'Not a HASH reference' error when using JSON::RPC::Client

Tags: perl, json-rpc

I'm a newbie in Perl.
I have a JSON-RPC server running at *http://localhost:19000* and I need to call *checkEmail()* method.

```
use JSON::RPC::Client;

my $client = new JSON::RPC::Client;
my $url    = 'http://localhost:19000';

my $callobj = { 
    method  => 'checkEmail',
    params  => [ 'rprikhodchenko@gmail.com' ],
};

my $res = $client->call($url, $callobj);

if($res) {
     if ($res->is_error) {
         print "Error : ", $res->error_message;
     }   
     else {
         print $res->result;
     }   
  }
  else {
     print $client->status_line;
  }
```

When I try to launch it it tells following:

```
perl ./check_ac.pl
Not a HASH reference at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/JSON/RPC/Client.pm line 193.
```

**UPD:**

Full stack-trace:

```
perl -MCarp::Always ./check_ac.pl
Not a HASH reference at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/JSON/RPC/Client.pm line 193
        JSON::RPC::ReturnObject::new('JSON::RPC::ReturnObject', 'HTTP::Response=HASH(0x9938d48)', 'JSON=SCALAR(0x96f1518)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/JSON/RPC/Client.pm line 118
        JSON::RPC::Client::call('JSON::RPC::Client=HASH(0x944a818)', 'http://localhost:19000', 'HASH(0x96f1578)') called at ./check_ac.pl line 11
```

Comment: Use `perl -MCarp::Always ./check_ac.pl` to get a full stack-trace and a better clue about where the problem is in your code.

Comment: It says "Can't locate Carp/Always.pm". I've tried install it using MCarp::Always but it cannot be found

Comment: Try to install Carp::Always, not MCarp::Always. The -M just means "use" from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

This error means that your JSON-RPC server is not actually one, inasmuch as it does not satisfy [requirement 7.3](http://json-rpc.org/wd/JSON-RPC-1-1-WD-20060807.html#Head25).  The error is triggered when `JSON::RPC::Client` assumes the document returned by the JSON-RPC service is well-formed (i.e., a JSON Object), and this assumptions turns out to have been in error.  A bug report to the author of `JSON::RPC::Client` would be an appropriate way to request better error messaging.

I would attack this sort of problem by finding out what the server was returning that was causing `JSON::RPC::Client` to choke.  Unfortunately, `JRC` fails to provide adequate hookpoints for finding this out, so you'll have to be a little bit tricky.

I don't like editing external libraries, so I recommend an extend-and-override approach to instrumenting traffic with the JSON-RPC server.  Something like this (in `check_ac.pl`):

```
use Data::Dumper qw();

package JSON::RPC::InstrumentedClient;
use base 'JSON::RPC::Client';

# This would be better done with Module::Install, but I'm limiting dependencies today.
sub _get {
    my ($self, @args) = @_;

    return $self->_dump_response($self->SUPER::_get(@args));
}

sub _post {
    my ($self, @args) = @_;

    return $self->_dump_response($self->SUPER::_post(@args));
}

sub _dump_response {
    my ($self, $response) = @_;

    warn Data::Dumper::Dump([$response->decoded_content], [qw(content)]);
    return $response;
}

package main;

my $client = JSON::RPC::InstrumentedClient->new();
my $url    = 'http://localhost:19000';

... # rest of check_ac.pl
```

This wraps the calls to `_get` and `_post` that `JSON::RPC::Client` makes internally in such a way as to let you examine what the web server actually said in response to the request we made.  The above code dumps the text content of the page; this might not be the right thing in your case and will blow up if an error is encountered.  It's a debugging aid only, to help you figure out from the client code side what is wrong with the server.

That's enough caveats for now, I think.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in [method `new` of `JSON::RPC::ReturnObject`](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/JSON-RPC/JSON/RPC/Client.pm.html#new-1-).

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $obj, $json) = @_;
    my $content = ( $json || JSON->new->utf8 )->decode( $obj->content );

    #...
# line 193
    $content->{error} ? $self->is_success(0) : $self->is_success(1);
    #...
}
```

`$content`'s value will be something returned from a [`JSON::decode()`](http://p3rl.org/JSON#decode) call. But looking at the documentation, it seems that `JSON->decode()` returns a scalar which could be a number, a string, an array reference, **or** a hash reference.

Unfortunately, `JSON::RPC::ReturnObject->new()` doesn't check what sort of thing `JSON->decode()` returned before trying to access it as a hashref.  Given your error, I'm going to go ahead and assume what it got in your case was *not* one.  :-)

I don't know if there's a way to force a fix from your code.  I'd recommend contacting the [author](http://p3rl.org/JSON%3a%3aRPC%3a%3aClient#AUTHOR) and letting him know about the issue, and/or [filing a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=JSON-RPC).

Comment: `JSON::RPC::Client` is behaving correctly by assuming the return value is a hashref; it's a requirement of the protocol.  For purposes of this question, of course, better error messaging would be better.

Comment: But `JSON::decode()` can still return other types of scalars, as I noted.  The `JSON` perldoc explicitly states that that is the case.  The bug is that `JSON::RPC::ReturnObject` should not assume that it will *always* get a hashref in `$content` unless the method it is calling to create it has made a guarantee that that is what it will always provide.  As you're saying, it appears there is another bug lurking in here somewhere (ie - why *wasn't* a hashref returned when it should have been?), but the "Not a HASH reference" error was caused by insufficient validation in `ReturnObject`'s ctor.

Comment: Yeah, there's some room for debate on whether it is `JRC`'s responsibility to provide good error messaging when it's interacting with something that isn't a JSON-RPC server (in fact, I read at least one comment in the `JRC` source as suggesting the author himself wasn't sure which way to go).  But I also don't think that pointing out this fact is by itself sufficiently helpful.

Comment: Fair enough.  I definitely focused on the Perl side of things rather than the JSON/RPC side.  Your answer will likely get him closer to where he needs to be.